# apply & funcall - the different results

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp, ansi-common-lisp

ANSI Common Lisp. 
Why I get an other answer in the last case?

```
(list 1 2 3 nil) ; (1 2 3 nil)
(funcall (function list) 1 2 3 nil) ; (1 2 3 nil)
(apply (function list) '(1 2 3 nil)) ; (1 2 3 nil)
(apply (function list) 1 2 3 nil) ; (1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`APPLY` expects as arguments:

- a function
- zero ... n arguments
- and then a list of arguments at the end

The function will basically be called with the result of `(list* 0-arg ... n-arg argument-list)`

Note that `(list* '(1 2 3))` evaluates to just `(1 2 3)`.

The arguments are called *spreadable argument list* in Common Lisp.

```
CL-USER 60 > (apply (function list) 1 2 3 nil)
(1 2 3)

CL-USER 61 > (apply (function list) (list* 1 2 3 nil))
(1 2 3)

CL-USER 62 > (apply (function list) (list* '(1 2 3)))
(1 2 3)
```

`APPLY` uses such a spreadable argument list by design. For example `(... 1 2 3 '(4 5))`. With `FUNCALL` you have to write the arguments as usual: `(... 1 2 3 4 5)`.

`APPLY` has a single purpose in Common Lisp: it allows functions to be called with computed argument lists. To make that a bit more convenient, this idea of the spreadable argument list has been used. It works the same for example in Emacs Lisp.

Imagine that you have a list of arguments and you want to add two arguments in front.

```
CL-USER 64 > (apply '+ args)
60

CL-USER 65 > (apply '+ 1 2 args)
63

CL-USER 66 > (apply '+ (append (list 1 2) args))
63
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand still: why I get not the `nil item at the end of list in the last case? I am a beginner in the ANSI Common Lisp, and I am reading the Paul Graham's book now.

Comment: @bush: last case: NIL is the empty list. `(list* 1 2 3 nil)` is adding 1, 2, 3, to the empty list. Thus `(1 2 3)`.